# Faster recognition of single tap on MKMapView (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapkit, mapkitannotation

In my iOS app I have an instance of an `MKMapView` and on single tap, I want to add a marker to the map. I've added a `UITapGestureRecognizer` and immediately noticed that it would fire even when a user double taps to zoom (or other interactions with the map).

I've implemented the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` method like this and this works, but makes the interaction very sluggish, because it obviously waits for the other gesture recognizers to fail.

```swift
    func gestureRecognizer(
        _ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer,
        shouldRequireFailureOf otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer
    ) -> Bool {
        guard gestureRecognizer == self.mapGestureRecognizer else {
            return false
        }

        return !(otherGestureRecognizer is UITapGestureRecognizer) && otherGestureRecognizer.state == .possible
    }
```

Is there any way to act quickly on a tap, without breaking the native gestures on the map view?

Comment: Not sure there is a direct solution to this as the mapView can't know if your tap is part of another gesture until it's waited to check.  My usual workaround for this is to use a long tap for adding markers to the map as this is a discrete event.

Comment: Thanks! That works for the biggest part, now there's only an issue where any first touch after the long press is missed or ignored. When I add this gesture recognizer and its handler to any other view, it works fine. On an `MKMapView` it blocks any next interaction, regardless of it's an actual new long press, or standard map interaction (like double tap, pan, pinch, etc).

Comment: Never had that.  Sure there's no other code left over from previous attempts?  Also you're not doing anything heavy/synchronous on the main thread that's blocking responses?

Comment: No nothing, also tried it in a completely clean view controller with only an `MKMapView` added to it.

Comment: I have created a minimal example that shows exactly this behavior. After a long press the next touch doesn't allow you to trigger it again, nor will it let you move the map, zoom, etc: https://pastebin.com/JLBQwt7w

Comment: Also seems `MKMapView` specific. If I change the map view to be any other type of view, it works fine.

Comment: Just tried it on a couple of my apps and not having the same behaviour.  Does it do this only if the next touch is immediately after, or even if there's a slight gap between touches?

Comment: Both. Even if I wait for ten seconds, the problem still occurs.

Comment: Weird!  Would be worth raising another question specifically about that and putting in the MapView code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure there is a direct solution to this as the mapView can't know if your tap is part of another gesture until it's waited to check. My usual workaround for this is to use a long tap for adding markers to the map as this is a discrete event